# Server 2008 R2 file access permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions, file-sharing

I'm finding it awkward to sort out permissions for file sharing and access on my LAN. I've created an account on the server node (as a normal user) and shared a drive that has 2 folders at the root, one is for personal file storage and the other shared files, if I connect to the shared area from a workstation running windows 7 and log-in using the account I created on the server, I can look through directories but can't look in some (which I wanted as I changed the permissions for that to happen), but my problem is although the permissions are set for this user account to have full control of the specific folder I can't create a folder in that area or upload files to that folder.

Could someone explain why this is?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: What are the share permissions for that user?

Comment: Full control. I've only shared the actual drive it's self because I want the user to be able to navigate through the directories below instead of it showing all the folders in the network area as I'd have to share each individual folder.

Comment: I think I seen something about NTFS permissions which would allow what I'm trying to achieve to happen. I tried it on a different drive a while ago and I think it worked though when I bring up the folder's properties it's not there just normal folder access permissions.

Comment: Did you click on the advanced button to bring up the advanced security settings? That's also where you can check the effective permissions as well.

Comment: Yes I did look there, and that account has full control. I just checked the effective permissions as well and every single box is ticked, that account is also the current owner of that folder and for all sub folders (when they are created, I haven't done so yet). I've also added this user to the Admin group and I still can't create a folder in that directory from the workstation running Win7. I'm finding this a little ridiculous, I've made sure all the networking services are running on the workstation too. When I try to create a folder it says I don't have permission to do so.

Comment: I've had a fiddle about and shared a folder with NTFS permissions instead of the drive and specific sub-folders, which works however I don't want it to be visible in the network share to users who don't have the permissions to access it. So this is an entire different question which I shall create a new thread for. Thanks for your help!